# How to compile TAL project (SMART TV)?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv, bbc-tal

I have an example project running on nodejs server (https://github.com/bbc/talexample), how to compile it into index.html, css and js to test in WebOS simulator?

Answer (score 0):

As far I remember TAL framework serves the content on the fly depends of the client UA. You can check some of the TAL core modules like tal-page-strategies and config/devices.

Based on these configs the framework sets the Doctype, meta and other parts of the HTML files in order to build the correct app (HTML5, CE-HTML...for Smart TV , HbbTV, videoconsoles...)

You can try to extract the js, CSS,  create the html..., but you will need to merge lot of code